# Why doesn't TensorFlow - tf.keras.utils.get_file read file from google drive?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here is my code:

```
from pathlib import Path
import gdown
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
#%tensorflow_version 1.x
import tensorflow as tf

# Link to goodle drive (archive file is called "internship_data.tar.gz")

_URL = 'https://drive.google.com/.tar.gz' 

zip_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('internship_data.tar.gz', origin=_URL, extract=True, archive_format='tar')


# Archive internship_data.tar.gz contains two folders: male и female

base_dir = Path(zip_dir).parent / "internship_data"
male_dir = base_dir / 'male'
female_dir = base_dir / 'female'

male_count = len(list(male_dir.glob("*")))
female_count = len(list(female_dir.glob("*")))

total = female_count + male_count

print('Male images:', male_count)
print('Female images:', female_count)
print("--")
print("Total images:", total)
```

Here i am trying to count the amount of images in each folder. It prints out zeros :(. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Don't put your full URL in your code snippet, we don't need to download the file ourselves. Unless you are absolutely certain it is ok to share your data with everyone on the internet, edit your question to alter the url so that we are not tempted to download some file we should not access.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [google drive downloader](https://pypi.org/project/googledrivedownloader/):

```
!pip install googledrivedownloader

from google_drive_downloader import GoogleDriveDownloader as gdd

gdd.download_file_from_google_drive(file_id='1-HUNDjcmSqdtMCvEkVlI0q43qlkcXBdK',
                                    dest_path='./internship_data.tar.gz')
```

And to extract data:

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open("internship_data.tar.gz")
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
```

Working with data:

```
base_dir = Path('internship_data')
male_dir = base_dir / 'male'
female_dir = base_dir / 'female'

male_count = len(list(male_dir.glob("*.jpg")))
female_count = len(list(female_dir.glob("*.jpg")))

total = female_count + male_count

print('Male images:', male_count)
print('Female images:', female_count)
print("--")
print("Total images:", total)
```

Comment: I already tried gdown:
    url = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-HUNDjcmSqdtMCvEkVlI0q43qlkcXBdK/view?usp=sharing/internship_data.tar.gz'
    output = 'internship_data.tar.gz'
    gdown.download(url, output, quiet=False)

Comment: Fixed dest_path parameter. gdown would work as well, right.

Comment: Yep, thnx, it worked... But the main idea was to work with file without downloading it, but reading it using batches in ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(batch_size=)

Comment: Well, tf.keras.utils.get_file() also downloads a file from a URL if it not already in the cache. After unpacking you'll be able to work with data using ImageDataGenerator.